# How do I use a 2D image as a texture on a single 2D face?

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor, 2d

I have a 2D JPG of roof tiles. I have a single face in my house mesh that will be the roof (so it is a 2D surface, though it's in 3D space). How do I get the 2D JPG to become the texture for only that face?

I have read several guides and the Blender manual, and asked [a related question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/140680/why-are-these-textures-diagonally-tiled/140684#140684) yesterday, but the guides and yesterday's answer all seem to assume that the aim is to get 2D image to spread across multiple faces of a 3D mesh. I want the 2D image to display on one face only.

I think that I have somehow missed a fundamental step or concept in my efforts so far (e.g. the picture below), so I would appreciate a step-by-step answer for a Blender newbie, please.

[image: Picture with a]

EDIT: Examples of the difference between what guides describe and what I am trying to do:

"UV mapping is the process of projecting a 2D image onto a 3D object. ... This means that your texture image isn’t going to be a square but rather 6 of them, which are oriented in such a way that folding them produces a cube." ([All3dp.com](https://all3dp.com/2/blender-how-to-add-a-texture/))

I want to project a 2D image onto a 2D surface (in 3D space). I have a simple texture image that is a rectangle that I want to project onto a rectangular face, not all the faces of a cube.

"An image/movie texture allows a two-dimensional image (which might be static or moving) to be wrapped around the surface of a three-dimensional object in some way. Alternatively, a procedural texture directly maps a predefined three-dimensional mathematical function to the surface coordinates of the object."([Wikibooks, *Blender:Noob to Pro*](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Texture_Settings))

I want to to directly map a two dimensional image to the 2D surface coordinates of the object (in 3D space).

Comment: What you are missing is the concept of UVs and texture coordinates. There are plenty of resources online to learn those.

Comment: Cegaton, thank you for your comment. I have added more information to clarify more information about the difference between what I have found in online guides and what I am trying to do. The online guides all seem to assume projection onto multiple faces. That is what I have done in the screenshot - but not what I want.

Comment: *"seem to assume that the aim is to get 2D image to spread across multiple faces of a 3D mesh"* not necessarily, rather than on as many faces as you assign image to. Use different materials and assign them to different faces. One material with the roof and the other one/-s - for the building. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough... 2D surfaces in 3D space!... Please use 3D or blender terminologies... There are differences between Blender and Picture Editing Softwares... Are you talking of Grease Pencils?... Do you import "Images as Plane"? Please make it clearer... How do you come about the 2D?

Comment: Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8697/how-do-i-put-an-image-texture-on-a-material-in-cycles The blender manual (yes there is one, and is not a video "tutorial") explains what you need to do: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/uv_image/uv/editing/unwrapping/index.html?highlight=unwrap

Comment: Israel Bamidele, I'm sorry that my terminology wasn't appropriate; I am all too aware that this is new to me. I will try to explain using an example. Think of a face where U==X and V==Y, and all the Z co-ordinates are the same. So the UV co-ordinate (0,0) become the XYZ co-ordinate (0,0,0), UV (0,1) becomes XYZ (0,1,0), UV (99,99) becomes XYZ (99,99,0), and so on. Although the co-ordinate system is 3D, only two of the dimensions are being manipulated in the mapping. If Blender has a tool/process focused on this situation, then that would be ideal.

Comment: Cegaton, thank you for your patience with me. I spent an hour struggling with the Blender manual before I asked this question. It says step 1 in the workflow is marking seams. The page on marking seams begins: "For many cases, using the Unwrap calculations of Cube, Cylinder, Sphere, or best fit will produce a good UV layout. However, for more complex meshes..." I do not want to wrap onto a cube, cylinder or sphere, only a single face. And surely a single face is less complex, not more complex, than a cube? Can I just skip marking seams?

Comment: @Matthew Could you please share your roof tile texture and the mesh for your roof?

Comment: @Dazotaro, thank you for offering to help. The mesh is [here](https://app.box.com/s/4o33xjyqzhwm96rejob7ny55zqm9ccpt) and the texture image is [here](https://github.com/jamespetts/Pak128.Britain-blends/raw/master/textures/grey_roof_slate.jpg) (both under Artistic License).